# Histogram/BarChart data replacement conundrum

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, histograms, charts

I am trying to make a histogram or bar chart for multiple large data sets, with 52 bins where I need to do the following operations:

A) Tally the counts per bin (which I have done reasonably easily using Flatten and Tally, shown below)[image]

B) And the more difficult problem as follows: Say I have a table such as

```
{{{{{1, 2, 3, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52}, 5.}}, {{{1, 12, 23, 46, 47}, 1.}}, {{{5, 6, 7, 8}, 
20.}}, {{{5, 6, 7, 8, 15, 16, 17}, 34.}}}}
```

where the first item in each group (1-52) represent the bins and the second item (5 in the first example) represents the value I want to plot.

Taking the first group as an example, I want to insert the number "5" into bins 1,2,3,46,47,48,49,50,51 and 52. As I iterate through my lists I want to keep filling the bins, so the second group has a "1" in bins 1,12,23,46, and 47, so I would want "6" in the bins that overlap. On and on and on through a decent chunk of data.

I've tried many different attempts at a solution using Thread, Collect, Gather, etc. I've tried making more tables or re-indexing, but I'm not closer to a solution than I was when I started. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
rawData = {{{{{1, 2, 3, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52}, 
     5.}}, {{{1, 12, 23, 46, 47}, 1.}}, {{{5, 6, 7, 8}, 
     20.}}, {{{5, 6, 7, 8, 15, 16, 17}, 34.}}}};
```

I don't like the nesting in the raw data but do not know how you are generating it. Working with it as it is, first step create cleaner data:

```
data = Sort@
  Flatten[{Map[Thread[Rule[#1[[1, 1]], #1[[1, 2]]]] &, rawData[[1]]], 
    Thread[Range[52] -> 0.]}]
```

Second step fill the bins by totalling what you have

```
totals=Values@GroupBy[data, First -> Last, Total]
```

> {6., 5., 5., 0., 54., 54., 54., 54., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 34.,
>       34., 34., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
>       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 6., 6., 5., 5.,
>       5., 5., 5.}

or just plot:

[image]

So two steps which I'd like to think are fairly intuitive.

Comment: Thanks! It's not entirely clear to me what is going on here but I'll study it over. It does appear to do what I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
collate[data_] := Block[{res=ConstantArray[0,52]},
    res[[#1]] += #2& @@@ Level[data, {-3}];
    res
]
```

Your example:

```
data = {{
    {{{1, 2, 3, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52}, 5.}},
    {{{1, 12, 23, 46, 47}, 1.}}, {{{5, 6, 7, 8}, 20.}},
    {{{5, 6, 7, 8, 15, 16, 17}, 34.}}
}};

collate[data]
```

> {6., 5., 5., 0, 54., 54., 54., 54., 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 34., 34., 34., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6., 6., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.}

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to look into what is going on here to understand it, I haven't used ConstantArray or Level yet but it certainly works!

Answer (score 1):

```
f = Function[{x, y}, MapAt[# + y[[2]]&, x, List /@ y[[1]]]];
Fold[f, Array[0 &, 52], data[[1, All, 1]]]
```

> {6., 5., 5., 0, 54., 54., 54., 54., 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 34., 34., 34., 
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6., 6., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.}